# android stable location provider

Tags: android, networking, gps, location, provider

I'm not sure which location providers I should use:
20 seconds is the maximum time I can manage without location.

The accuracy is less important for me, I can manage with accuracy of 500m.

Comment: so what is your question exactly

Comment: which location provider should I use? network? gps? both?

Comment: see my answer, and read about the locationmanager

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [location manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) class. It will give you the information about location. And because you need an accuracy of 500m , I would suggest you to use gps, as networks(assuming you mean cellular) will have a lesser accuracy.